# Changing value of db_cache_advice

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to change the value of db_cache_advice but i'm keep getting the same error, whatever value i'm changing it to. Any advice?

```
SQL> alter system set db_cache_advice = ready;
alter system set db_cache_advice = ready
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because specified value is invalid
ORA-00381: cannot use both new and old parameters for buffer cache size specification
```

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using and why do you want to change this parameter?

Comment: What is the current state of this parameter? It should be ON before you make it as READY. Try to run `alter system set db_cache_advice = on;` and then `alter system set db_cache_advice = ready;`

Comment: The version I'm using is 10g and i'm trying to collect performance measurements hence the use of the parameter. The current state is ON, but following the answer from Nicholas both parameters are set up. I need revert everything to its default and try to change the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle prohibits simultaneous use of some initialization parameters, `db_cache_advice` is one of them. You cannot specify `db_cache_advice` initialization parameter if, for example you have already specified `db_block_buffers` in your initialization parameter file. Note from the Database Reference:

> Note: DB_BLOCK_BUFFERS cannot be combined with the dynamic
>   DB_CACHE_SIZE parameter; combining these parameters in the same
>   parameter file will produce an error.

You can get the list, `db_cache_advice` initialization parameter is not compatible with, either from the definition of a particular initialization parameter or from the explanation of the cause of [ORA-00381 error](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e0.htm#sthref305)

So, you need to check what initialization parameters that are incompatible with `dba_cache_advice` are already in use and decide, whether you are going to keep using those parameters or replace them with new one.